# SVN log - get only revisions with pattern in comments

Tags: bash, svn

I am trying to create a simple bash script that verify which revisions do not contain a certain pattern in its comment.

For example:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r272876 | user | 2014-10-30 11:15:06 +0000 (Qui, 30 Out 2014) | 1 line

PATTERN-17278: My comment.
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r272877 | user | 2014-10-31 12:06:41 +0000 (Sex, 31 Out 2014) | 1 line

My problematic revision
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r273529 | user | 2014-10-20 17:45:36 +0000 (Seg, 20 Nov 2014) | 2 lines

PATTERN-17297: Erro no angulo do vetor velocidade
------------------------------------------------------------------------    
r273797 | user | 2014-10-14 11:35:05 +0000 (Ter, 4 Nov 2014) | 1 line

Other problematic revision
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r274096 | user | 2014-08-26 11:18:31 +0000 (Qua, 5 Nov 2014) | 1 line

And another
```

How do I easily print revisions like r272877, r273797 and r274096 in a list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's define a shell variable that contains the dashed line that SVN uses to separate log entries:

```
RS='\n------------------------------------------------------------------------'
```

Now, we can print all all log entries that do *not* contain `pattern`:

```
svn log . | awk -v "RS=$RS" '!/pattern/{print RS,$0}'
```

Alternatively, if you wanted only log entries that *do* contain `pattern`, then use:

```
svn log . | awk -v "RS=$RS" '/pattern/{print RS,$0}'
```

#### How it works

- `-v "RS=$RS"`

  `awk` divides its input into records and reads in one record at a time.  Here, we define the record separator to be what SVN uses to separate log entries.
- `!/pattern/{print RS,$0}`

  `awk` implicitly loops through every record in the input.  This looks for records that do *not* contain `pattern` where `pattern` can be any regular expression.  The exclamation point, `!`, means "not".  Records that meet this criterion, are printed.  `print RS,$0` tells `awk` to print the record separator and then the contents of this log entry.

My version of subversion uses 72 dashes as the record separator.  I don't know if this is subject to change from version to version.  If it is, you may need to adjust the definition of `RS` appropriately.

#### Example

Using your sample log output as saved in a file called `log`, this prints all records not containing `PATTERN-17278`:

```
$ awk -v "RS=$RS" '!/PATTERN-17278/{print RS,$0}' log

------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
r272877 | user | 2014-10-31 12:06:41 +0000 (Sex, 31 Out 2014) | 1 line

My problematic revision

------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

#### Alternative output: Return only the revision numbers

The revision numbers are the first item after the record separator.  To print out just revision numbers, use:

```
svn log . | awk -v "RS=$RS" '!/pattern/{print $1}'
```

Using the sample input [before question updated] as an example:

```
$ awk -v "RS=$RS" '!/PATTERN-17278/{print $1}' log2
r2728
```

#### Using a variable pattern

```
awk -v "RS=$RS" -v p='PATTERN-17278|PATTERN-17297' '$0 !~ p{print $1}' log3
r272877
r273797
r274096
```

Comment: It's works. But I am still having a trouble: my pattern is a bash variable and the single quotes do not allow me to use it. (I'm sorry for my possible mistakes, I'm still learning english)

Comment: One thing more: I need only the numbers of revisions. In this case I add `| grep -o "^r[0-9]\+"` to your awk output ;)

Comment: @NFTX That works but using `grep` is not really necessary.  See updated answer.

Comment: I changed my example for to be more clear. With this "alternative output" I am not be able to print a list (I don't know why). I am still using the `grep`.
One thing more: I changed `"RS=$RS"` to `"RS=$RS,PATTERN=$PATTERN"` to use the bash variable "pattern"

Comment: @NFTX I updated the answer with an example of using a variable pattern and testing it against the example log from the current version of the question.  _"I am not be able to print a list"_  If that is still a problem with the current solution, I would want to know more precisely what output you do see.

Comment: Thank you. It's working. My command line is `svn log -r ${initialRevision}:${finalRevision} ${URL} | awk -v "RS=$RS" -v PREFIX="$prefix" '$0 !~ PREFIX{print $1}'`. I'm sorry for not be clear, but I just check the "pattern" and I ignore its enumeration (In your example would only `p='PATTERN'`).